# Qt 5.0.1 for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, software-center, qt

So i've asked before, but the answer was that i should install Ubuntu Phone SDK, which, doesn't seem to be the best way. I've looked on Software Center but it's not there. Downloading though the Qt site is the only option i've got?

I want to both develop and run Qt Applications. I don't want to develop for Ubuntu Phone.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Run programs that need Qt? Develop Qt software? Why don't you want to install the Ubuntu Phone SDK? Do you want to develop Qt 5.0.1 software that is *not* for Ubuntu Phone? Please provide more details by *editing your question*, so that this can get a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: Edited. Will answer here too. I want both develop and run Qt applications. I don't want to develop for Ubuntu Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the newest version from [Qt Project Downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads). It comes as a .run file. After you make the file executable, you can install the program from the command line with: `sudo sh ./filename.run`.

Comment: I assume, Qt on Windows come with auto-updater. Does work the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: No, but if you have installed the sdk from the website you can use the maintenance tool/installer to update.